# open new fxml in browser

Tags: browser, javafx, fxml

I use this code to launch login.FXML from the controller of another fxml

```
   Pane myPane = (Pane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/login/login.fxml"));
    Scene myScene = new Scene(myPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

the problem is : when I start the application in a browser , everything is ok until the code above is reached because it runs login.fxml on desktop but not in the browser.
How should I modify the code to let open the new fxml in the browser ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I resolved the problem by working with the same stage instead of creating new one , thanks , have a nice day.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because poster added comment saying "I resolved the problem. Thanks. Have a nice day". 

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to [sign the application jars](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABJGFBH) to allow a JavaFX 2.x application to run inside a browser using the higher security permissions that are required for fxml based applications as described in: [RT-23622 JavaFX applications with FXML fail while running on browser](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23622).

Comment: I think signing is not the problem because the jars are self signed with nebeans, I also  signed them with jarsigner , nothing changed.
My project contain 2 fxmls, the first runs kk in the browser... , when I push the button to launch the second fxml , it run in desktop and not in the browser.